# BIT Shifting operator not working

Tags: c++, c

The variable z has been declared as long long unsigned int so the range is 
0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 but the following program fails to compute the required values after some iterations.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long unsigned int z=2;

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",z<<i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` is for printing `int`, not `long long unsigned int`.

Comment: As an aside, if you are using `gcc`, then compiling with the `-Wall` option will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Use `cout << (z<< i) << "\n";` which will output regardless of type.  You did include the C++ tag!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `printf` statement.

### Updated code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long unsigned int z = 2;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<40; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (z << i) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
2147483648
4294967296
8589934592
17179869184
34359738368
68719476736
137438953472
274877906944
549755813888
1099511627776
```

Comment: Spot on and substantially faster than myself.  Good thing I'm a Java developer.

Answer (score 2):

Try `printf("%llu\n",z<<i);`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `%d` is for printing `int`, not larger types.

The following works:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long unsigned int z=2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 40 ; i++)
    {
       std::cout << (z<<i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `"%lld\n"` in the `printf` formatting string, not `"%d\n"`.